# HList Ops - how are type classes constracted?

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless, hlist

Can someone explain why this code compiles and works like a charm:

```
val a = true :: Some(5) :: true :: HNil
a.select[Some[Int]]                                // Some(5)
```

but this one fails:

```
def foo[HL <: HList](a: HL): Some[Int] = {
  a.select[Some[Int]]                              // fails
}
```

```
Implicit not found: shapeless.Ops.Selector[tp, Some[Int]]. You requested an element of type Some[Int], but there is none in the HList tp.
a.select[Some[Int]]
```

I don't want to pass a instance of Selector.

I also tried:

```
type tp = Boolean :: Option[Int] :: Boolean :: HNil
def foo(a: tp): Some[Int] = a.select[Some[Int]]       // fails
foo(a)
```

but it failed with a message:

```
Implicit not found: shapeless.Ops.Selector[tp, Some[Int]]. You requested an element of type Some[Int], but there is none in the HList tp.
a.select[Some[Int]]
```

Comment: For the same reason you can't take the square root of an array. The type system is forbidding you from doing things that it can't prove are correct. When you're working with `HList`s, you're working with known types, and you have to prove that the operations are valid. That's what a `Selector` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pYjqlyLOTZOwhNxnt4b8rw):

```
def foo[HL <: HList](a: HL)
                    (implicit sel: ops.hlist.Selector[HL, Some[Int]]): Some[Int] = {
  a.select[Some[Int]]                       
}
```

The full signature of `select` is

```
def select[U](implicit selector: hlist.Selector[HL,U]): U
```

There is an implicit parameter `selector`, so you must provide one.

Comment: But I don't want to pass an implicit of Selector. Is there a way to achieve it with type bounties with generics?

Comment: You **do not need** to pass an implicit one. You can just invoke it like `a.select[Some[Int]]`， i.e. `select(a)`. The implicit parameter will be auto filled. @OskarFurmańczuk